# Deixar palavras do meu HTML em negrito usando RegEx

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Basicamente, preciso selecionar todas as palavras "pattern" do meu HTML com RegEx e depois substitui-las por sua versão em negrito através do JavaScript.

Meu código funciona, porém, só para o primeiro elemento, por algum motivo ele não deixa os outros em negrito. (obs: esse mesmo código foi usado para deixar algumas palavras em maiúsculo, e funcionou perfeitamente em todas).

```js
    function patternEmNegrito() {
        const regex = /pattern/ig
        const texto = document.querySelector('.texto')
        const resultado = texto.innerHTML.match(regex)
    
        let textoFinal = texto.innerHTML
        for(let i = 0; i < resultado.length; i++){
            textoFinal = textoFinal.replace(resultado[i], `<b>${resultado[i]}</b>`)
        }
        return texto.innerHTML = textoFinal
    }
    patternEmNegrito()
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>selecionando e modificando textos com regEx</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>texto</h1>
    
        <div class="resultado">
    
        </div>
        
        <div class="texto">
            <h1>What Is a Regular Expression?</h1>
            <p> regular expression is a sequence of characters that forms a search pattern.</p>
            
            <p>When you search for data in a text, you can use this search pattern to describe what you are searching for.</p>
            
            <p>A regular expression can be a single character, or a more complicated pattern.</p>
            
            <p>Regular expressions can be used to perform all types of text search and text replace operations.</p>
        </div>
        <script src="./regex.js"></script>
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com maiúscula funciona porque o JS é case sensitive, ou seja, após ele alterar a primeira ocorrência, ela já não é mais encontrada pelo replace e a cada volta no laço `for` irá buscar novamente a primeira ocorrência que ainda está em minúscula.

Isso é porque o replace só substitui a primeira ocorrência. No seu caso aí, está criando 3 `<b>` aninhados na primeira ocorrência da string *pattern*, porque o replace dentro do laço só está substituindo o primeiro *pattern* encontrado.

Não precisa de um laço `for` para isso e nem funcionaria mesmo, porque mesmo iterando a array criada pelo `.match()`, não altera a forma do replace funcionar. O replace aceita Regex e com a flag `g` já substitui tudo de uma vez.

Não é preciso nem o `.match`, mas mantive no exemplo abaixo só para ilustração:

```js
function patternEmNegrito() {
    const regex = /pattern/ig;
    const texto = document.querySelector('.texto')
    const resultado = texto.innerHTML.match(regex)

    let textoFinal = texto.innerHTML
    const re_replace = new RegExp(resultado[0], 'g');
    textoFinal = textoFinal.replace(re_replace, `<b>${resultado[0]}</b>`)
    return texto.innerHTML = textoFinal
}
patternEmNegrito()
```

```html
<h1>texto</h1>

<div class="resultado">

</div>

<div class="texto">
  <h1>What Is a Regular Expression?</h1>
  <p> regular expression is a sequence of characters that forms a search pattern.</p>

  <p>When you search for data in a text, you can use this search pattern to describe what you are searching for.</p>

  <p>A regular expression can be a single character, or a more complicated pattern.</p>

  <p>Regular expressions can be used to perform all types of text search and text replace operations.</p>
</div>
```

### Apenas `.replace()`

Usando apenas replace, você poderia fazer assim:

```js
function patternEmNegrito() {
    const padrao = 'pattern' // padrão a ser buscado
    const regex = new RegExp(padrao, 'g') // cria o objeto RegExp com o padrão e a flag "g"
    const texto = document.querySelector('.texto') // seleciona a div
    const textoFinal = texto.innerHTML.replace(regex, `<b>${padrao}</b>`) // substitui todas as ocorrências

    return texto.innerHTML = textoFinal // altera o innerHTML da div
}
patternEmNegrito()
```

```html
<h1>texto</h1>

<div class="resultado">

</div>

<div class="texto">
  <h1>What Is a Regular Expression?</h1>
  <p> regular expression is a sequence of characters that forms a search pattern.</p>

  <p>When you search for data in a text, you can use this search pattern to describe what you are searching for.</p>

  <p>A regular expression can be a single character, or a more complicated pattern.</p>

  <p>Regular expressions can be used to perform all types of text search and text replace operations.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: muito obrigado, me ajudou bastante! mas ainda tenho uma dúvida, você disse que o replace só mudaria a primeira ocorrência e que o laço for não funcionaria... mas eu havia feito uma função com esse mesmo código, porém deixando as palavras em maiúsculas, e funcionou. vou deixar o código abaixo:

Comment: function deixarMaiusculo() {
    const regex = /expression/ig
    const texto = document.querySelector('.texto')

    const resultado = texto.innerHTML.match(regex)
    console.log(resultado)

    let textoFinal = texto.innerHTML
    for(let i = 0; i < resultado.length; i++){
        textoFinal = textoFinal.replace(resultado[i], resultado[i].toUpperCase())
    }
    return texto.innerHTML = textoFinal
}

Comment: Com maiúscula funciona porque o JS é case sensitive, ou seja, após ele alterar a primeira ocorrência, ela já não é mais encontrada pelo replace, e assim por diante.

Answer (score 1):

Apenas complementando a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/393154/112052), existe uma situação em que a regex pode causar problemas: se eu tiver a string "pattern" dentro de uma tag, como por exemplo no atributo de um `input`:

```js
function patternEmNegrito() {
    const regex = /pattern/ig;
    const texto = document.querySelector('.texto');
    const resultado = texto.innerHTML.match(regex);

    let textoFinal = texto.innerHTML;
    const re_replace = new RegExp(resultado[0], 'g');
    textoFinal = textoFinal.replace(re_replace, `<b>${resultado[0]}</b>`);
    console.log(textoFinal);
    return texto.innerHTML = textoFinal;
}
patternEmNegrito()
```

```html
<div class="texto">
  <form>
    <input type="text" pattern="[a-z]+">
  </form>
</div>
```

O resultado é que o `innerHTML` será:

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" <b>pattern</b>="[a-z]+">
</form>
```

Repare que o atributo `pattern` foi substituído por `<b>pattern</b>`, mas como isso está dentro da tag, ela passa a ser inválida e o `input` não é mais exibido corretamente pelo browser.

Se você tem certeza que seu HTML não tem a string "pattern" como atributo de uma tag, não há problema. Mas se quiser tratar também estes casos, a regex é um pouco mais complicada:

```js
function patternEmNegrito() {
    const texto = document.querySelector('.texto');
    let re = /(\bpattern\b)(?![^<]*>)/gi;
    texto.innerHTML = texto.innerHTML.replace(re, "<b>$1</b>");
}
patternEmNegrito()
```

```html
<div class="texto">
  <form>
    <input type="text" pattern="[a-z]+">
  </form>
  <h1>What Is a Regular Expression?</h1>
  <p> regular expression is a sequence of characters that forms a search pattern.</p>

  <p>When you search for data in a text, you can use this search pattern to describe what you are searching for.</p>

  <p>A regular expression can be a single character, or a more complicated pattern.</p>

  <p>Regular expressions can be used to perform all types of text search and text replace operations.</p>

  <p>Pattern, PATTERN and pattERN are replaced, keeping their original case.</p>

</div>
```

A regex é `(\bpattern\b)(?![^<]*>)` (as barras não fazem parte da regex em si, elas só servem para delimitá-la).

Primeiro temos a palavra "pattern" cercada por `\b`, que é o [atalho para "fronteira de palavra"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word-boundary). Isso garante que a palavra "pattern" será considerada somente se não houver outros caracteres alfanuméricos antes e depois (isso evita casos como "antipattern", por exemplo: como há uma letra antes do `p`, a regex  desconsidera e não faz a substituição).

Eu coloquei isso dentro de parênteses para formar um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Isso será importante depois, na hora da substituição.

Depois temos um [*negative lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (a expressão dentro de `(?!...)`), que serve para verificar se algo não existe à frente. No caso, dentro deste *lookahead* temos `[^<]*>`, que é "zero ou mais caracteres que não sejam `<`", seguido do caractere `>`.

Ou seja, a regex procura pela palavra "pattern", desde que logo depois **não** tenha vários caracteres que não sejam a abertura de tag + fechamento de tag. Resumindo, a palavra "pattern" não pode estar dentro de uma tag (entre o `<` e o `>`, seja como atributo, seja como o valor de um atributo).

Na substituição eu uso `$1`, que é uma variável especial que corresponde ao primeiro grupo de captura (ao primeiro par de parênteses, que no caso será a palavra "pattern").

Eu poderia usar a própria palavra "pattern" na substituição, mas como foi usada a [*flag*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags_2) `i`, a regex se torna *case insensitive*, o que quer dizer que ela irá substituir "pattern", "PATTERN", "PAtterN" e qualquer outra combinação de maiúsculas e minúsculas. Sendo assim, usar `$1` garante que você usará exatamente a mesma string que foi capturada, mantendo as maiúsculas e minúsculas (estou dizendo isso porque no seu código original você usou esta *flag*, dando a entender que no texto pode ter esta variação entre maiúsculas e minúsculas).

Também usei a *flag* `g`, que faz com que todas as ocorrências sejam substituídas. Se você não usá-la, somente a primeira ocorrência será substituída.

Por fim, repare que você pode usar o `replace` diretamente. Não precisa fazer um `match` para depois pegar o resultado e usar na substituição. O `replace` já procura pelas ocorrências da regex e só faz a substituição caso algo seja encontrado (ou seja, ela já tenta encontrar um *match*, e caso encontre, substitui o trecho encontrado).

Comment: sensacional! obrigado por compartilhar seu conhecimento conosco